# Inclusion-exclusion principle, password combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I am trying to calculate password of 10 character that must contain at least:

- 1 lower case character (26)
- 1 digit (10)
- 1 special digit (8)

I did this,I just want to confirm I used the principle correctly.

Here is my answer

```
44^10 - (26 + 10)^10 - (10 + 8)^10 - (26 + 8)^10 + (26^10 + 10^10 + 8^10)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By calculate, do you perchance mean: *count* the distinct arrangements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; you are applying the principle of counting "including all, excluding (all but 1), and including (all but 2) again" correctly.

$$(26+10+8)^{10} - \big((26 + 10)^{10} + (10 + 8)^{10} + (26 + 8)^{10}\big) + \big(26^{10} + 10^{10} + 8^{10}\big)$$

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a bit more? E.g. what is "26 + 10 ^ 10" all about? Maybe you would like to create a visualization of the space of combinations?

Comment: There are $n^{10}$ ways to make ten independent choices each with $n$ options.   $(26+10)$ counts the options of lower case letters and digits.  Thus there are $(26+10)^{10}$ ten-character-passwords without any special keys.  @Carlin'tVeld